# Can Spawns in Screeps use memory?

Tags: memory, screeps

Can Spawns retain memory? I can't find a precise answer and my code shows that Spawns do not retain memory, which is not what I read in the API and Docs.

http://screeps.wikia.com/wiki/Memory

My code to test if Spawns have memory is as follow (the meaningful extract):

```
StructureSpawn.prototype.whatever = function() {
  this.memory.count = 12;
  console.log(this.memory.count);
}
```

Now, the code above, when run by main.js, return indeed 12, but when I comment out the assignment line, it loses the value and returns undefined.

What exactly am I missing?

I get that I cannot store objects in memory, but numbers?! Not even strings?

Neither this work, by the way (copied from the docs).

```
Game.spawns.Spawn1.memory.count = 12;
```

Answer (score 3):

myspawn.memory is just a reference to Memory.spawns[myspawn].

All variables are run through JSON.stringify on the way in and JSON.parse on the way out.

```
let myobj= { 'hello' : 'world' }
Games.spawns[myspawn].memory.remember= myobj;
console.log(Games.spawns[myspawn].memory.remember.hello);
```

is the same as

```
let myobj= { 'hello' : 'world' }
Memory.spawns[myspawn].remember= myobj;
console.log(Memory.spawns[myspawn].remember.hello);
```

To expand on that, you can make variables anywhere in the Memory structure, even right on the root. In your console try copy pasting

`Memory.foo = "bar";`

Then check your memory tab, and view the Memory root. From the memory tab you can either modify it directly or delete it entirely.

You might be addressing the spawn incorrectly. Try typing this series of commands into the console, replacing "blech" with the name of your spawn

```
delete Game.spawns.blech.memory;  
console.log(JSON.stringify(Game.spawns.blech.memory));    
Game.spawns.blech.memory = {"Hello" : "World"}; 
console.log(JSON.stringify(Game.spawns.blech.memory));
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, so if I understand correctly, you do not directly create a property on the object Spawn, like for example:

const spawn = Game.spawns[name];
spawn.memory.something = 'something';

Because that seems not to work. I made more trials and where Creeps can store in their memory any valid json entry (including arrays and objects), the same is not true for Spawns.

Or maybe I address the Spawn in incorrect way, I'll check that out again.

Thanks for your suggestion, though. I'll try that too as well.

Comment: I added some more copy paste code in the above answer, so you can verify how memory works in the console.